# How to calculate convection between a hot and a cold area through a circular hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, diffusion, convection

Consider the below problem:

where we have two half infinite worlds with $T_2 < T_1$ and a circular hole with the diameter of $D$ in an infinite isolating wall. There is no pressure difference between the two areas. There is gravity downwards, but we can ignore it to simplify the problem for now. I want to calculate the heat load from the hot area to the cold area in the final steady-state condition.

I don't know where to start. I would appreciate it if you could point me to the right direction.

**P.S.1.** I'm not quite sure, but I think in the absence of gravity it becomes a conduction problem in steady state. If there should be gravity then it becomes a fluid dynamics problem that should probably be solved using [convection–diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation).

**P.S.2.** I have also posted the question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/thermodynamics/comments/pyjfmv/how_to_calculate_convection_between_a_hot_and_a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: I'm not an expert in heat transfer, but is this situation even possible? How can there be no pressure difference and no density difference when the temperatures are not the same?

Comment: @Mechanic you are actually right  Then I guess the either of them must be different.

Comment: @Mechanic I edited, so now only the pressures are the same.

Comment: @Foad What "gravity downwards" means in your sketch?

Comment: You can solve for the steady state temperature distribution by solving Laplace's equation in elliptic coordinates. This allows a straightforward separation of variables giving a general solution as
$$U(\mu,\nu) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \cosh(n\mu)\cos(n\nu) + B_n \cosh(n\mu)\sin(n\nu) + C_n \sinh(n\mu)\cos(n\nu)+D_n \sinh(n\mu)\sin(n\nu)$$ for constants $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$. The gradient of $U$ gives the heat flow.

Comment: In the final steady state, the temperature is uniform everywhere.

Comment: @ChetMiller in reality the hot area is being heated actively and the cold area is being cooled actively. But in the theoretical problem above I assumed the two words are infinite from all other directions.

Comment: I can help you with this.  The first step in analyzing this is to envision what the isotherms would look like in the case where convection is not present.  What do you think the isotherms would look like for this case?

Comment: @ChetMiller to be honest I am not sure what do you mean by the term "isotherms".   Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Isotherms are the geometric locuses of constant temperature within the fluid.

Comment: @ChetMiller I think Anders's suggestion to use elliptic coordinate system is a good idea.

Comment: I'm not asking you to solve the equations.  All I'm asking is "what do you think the isotherms of the undisturbed temperature field look like (a) far from the hole and (b) close to the hole?"

Comment: @ChetMiller please see the picture at the end of [this post](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/239224-using-openfoam-run-2d-convection-diffusion-simulation-compressible-steady-s.html#post818429). This is how I envision the flow to be in the steady state phase.